# How to write this LINQ for applying business logic?

Tags: c#, linq, c#-4.0

I am trying to apply some business logic.
My question about usage of LINQ on the following object models to *apply*  the business logic. I have the following objects populated accordingly:

```
public class Waiver
{
   public string Id { get; set; }
   public int Type { get; set; }
   public decimal Amount { get; set; }
}
```

Business Logic to be applied:

**1.) Apply Line Item waiver**
If LineItem Waiver [Type] is 1111  deduct the LineItem Waiver amount off Unit Price
If LineItem Waiver [Type] is 2222  deduct LineItem WaiverAmount as a Percentage Off Unit Price
If LineItem Waiver [Type] is 3333  deduct the LineItem Waiver amount off (Line Price = Qty * Unit Price)
If LineItem Waiver [Type] is 4444  deduct LineItem Waiver Amount as a Percentage Off Line Price

**2.) Apply Order waiver**
If Order Waiver [Type] is 4444  deduct Order Waiver amount Off Total Order Price after applying LineItem Waivers
If Order Waiver [Type] is 8888  deduct Order Waiver amount as Percentage Off Order Price after applying LineItem Waivers

What is the best way to achieve this?

```
GetWaivedPrice(decimal unitPrice, int qty, IEnumerable<Waiver> waiver)
```

Can `GetWaivedPrice` be written as a single LINQ method with appropriate mapping for all the discount types?

This is what I am trying to achieve, preferably as a well written LINQ method:

```
private decimal GetWaivedPrice(decimal unitPrice, int qty, 
                                           IEnumerable<Waiver> waiver)
        {
            //Pseudo code shown for clarifying intent
            decimal waivedLineItemAmount = 0m;

            if waiver.Select(d => d.Type == 1111)
            //then apply the business logic on the unit price accordingly        
            if waiver.Select(d => d.Type == 2222)
            //then apply the business logic on the unit price accordingly  
            if waiver.Select(d => d.Type == 3333)
            //then apply the business logic on the unit price accordingly  

            return waivedLineItemAmount;

        }
```

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific what you have problem with? Why JSON is part of the question about doing some (seemingly trivial) operations on data? What is your definition of "better" for this case (readability, code size, number of lines...)?

Comment: My problem is the bestway way to write the GetWaivedPrice method for applying line level waivers. The JSON has been just as a sample frmat for what the input looks like.

Comment: I've removed all unrelated JSON code, constructors and whitespace - feel free to improve if necessary. Please show your attempt on implementing `GetWaivedPrice` - current method signature shows that you unlikely tried to write one... Also you still need to add criteria for "better"...

Comment: Voted to reopen... Side note: I know most people are not capable reading more than one statement at a time (I'm one of them :). So let's try single statement: please provide your criteria for picking "the best way" - what is "better" in your case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see the case for LINQ here. Just apply each `Waver` in turn.

```
    private decimal GetWaivedPrice(decimal unitPrice, int qty, 
                                       IEnumerable<Waiver> waiver)
    {
        //Pseudo code shown for clarifying intent
        decimal waivedLineItemAmount = 0m;

        //apply all waivers
        foreach (var w in waiver) {
         switch (w.Type) { 
          case 1111:
           waivedLineItemAmout += someComputation();
           break;
          case 2222:
           waivedLineItemAmout += someComputation();
           break;
          case 3333:
           waivedLineItemAmout += someComputation();
           break;
         }
        }

        return waivedLineItemAmount;
    }
```

You can formulate this with `Enumerable.Aggregate` if you insist on LINQ and a purely functional style but a simple loop seems just fine here.

Comment: How to with Enumerable.Aggregate?

Comment: `waivers.Aggregate(0m, (currentWaivedLineItemAmount, w) => computeNewAmount(currentWaivedLineItemAmount, w))`. When you fully write this out it is the same code, just less understandable.

Answer (score 1):

I am not seeing the need for linq per-se, but maybe Object Oriented design.

I would instead have the waiver handle the business logic in a method call such as what you have now.

```
public class Waiver
{
   public string Id { get; set; }
   public int Type { get; set; }
   public decimal Amount { get; set; }

   public decimal GetWaivedPrice(decimal unitPrice, int qty) { ... }

}
```

By doing that it would facilitate any future linq projections or operations such as this grouping and of course centralize the business logic for future maintenance.

```
var groupedResult = myWaivers.Select(wv => new
    {
       Type = wv.Type,
       WaivedPrice = wv.GetWaivedPrice( unitPrice, qty)
    } )
                             .GroupBy(wv => wv.Type);
```

Answer (score 1):

How about that:

```
private static Dictionary<int, Func<decimal, int, Waiver, decimal>> _logic
    = new Dictionary<int, Func<decimal, int, Waiver, decimal>>() {
        { 2222, (a, q, w) => a + w.Amount },
        { 3333, (a, q, w) => a + w.Amount },
        { 3333, (a, q, w) => a + w.Amount }
    };

private static decimal GetWaivedPrice(decimal unitPrice, int qty, 
                                   IEnumerable<Waiver> waiver)
{
    return waiver.Aggregate(0m, (a, s) => _logic[s.Type](a, qty, s), a => a);
}
```

Of course you have to update `_logic` dictionary with your discount logic to make it work.

Answer (score 1):

Business rules are isolated into separate concerns (deductions and strategy) and it's now pretty LINQ-ish!

```
// Create a data structure to model the deductions themselves
public class LineItemDeduction
{
    public decimal UnitPriceAmount { get; set; }
    public decimal UnitPricePercentage { get; set; }
    public decimal LinePriceAmount { get; set; }
    public decimal LinePricePercentage { get; set; }

    // Assumed that waivers are distinct and are not composed together, only applied on the listed price.
    public decimal CalculateWaivedPrice(decimal unitPrice, int qty)
    {
        return ((unitPrice - UnitPriceAmount - (unitPrice * UnitPricePercentage)) * qty) - LinePriceAmount - (unitPrice * qty * LinePricePercentage);
    }
}

// Calculate the deductions
private LineItemDeduction CalculateLineItemDeductionStrategy(LineItemDeduction deduction, Waiver waiver)
{
    switch (waiver.Type) { 
      case 1111:
       deduction.UnitPriceAmount += waiver.Amount;
       break;
      case 2222:
       deduction.UnitPricePercentage += waiver.Amount;
       break;
      case 3333:
       deduction.LinePriceAmount += waiver.Amount;
       break;
      case 4444:
       deduction.LinePricePercentage += waiver.Amount;
       break;
     }

     return deduction;
}

// Extension method only for LineItem but it's the same principle for order waivers
public static decimal GetWaivedPrice(this IEnumerable<Waiver> waivers, decimal unitPrice, int qty, Func<LineItemDeduction, Waiver, LineItemDeduction> deductionStrategy)
{
    return waivers.Aggregate(
        new LineItemDeduction(),
        deductionStrategy,
        d => d.CalculateWaivedPrice(unitPrice, qty)
    );
}

// Now to get the waived price
var waivedPrice = waivers.GetWaivedPrice(unitPrice, qty, CalculateLineItemDeductionStrategy);
```